# Xstream jar working on Dev Server but not working on QA server

Tags: weblogic, xstream

Due to some security reasons, I'm using xtream-1.4.17.jar in my code. It's working fine on Dev server with my code, but when I'm deploying my code to QA server I'm getting a "class not found exception: com.thoughtworks.xstream.HierarchicalStreamDriver" this error. I'm using Weblogic server on dev & QA both, I have also updated the server classpath with jar name but still getting the same error

Finding: On dev server I'm getting the same error but my EAR is getting deployed successfully and its status become ACTIVE

Comment: How did you set the classpath ?
Did you check the server classpath ? It is written in the stdout when the server starts.

Comment: Yes I have added in server classpath. It is there in stdout.